# Weird warnings with THREE.js when starting animation

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a THREE.js animation where I make turn a sphere. This animation has 2 versions, a first one which is a raw version and a second one which is more structured with the using of function.

On Firefox, When I load this animation and after clicking on image, I have a lot of THREE.js weird warnings like this:

```
THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() vertex WARNING: 0:1: extension 'GL_ARB_gpu_shader5' is not supported
 1: precision highp float;
2: precision highp int;
3: #define SHADER_NAME MeshPhongMaterial
4: #define VERTEX_TEXTURES
5: #define GAMMA_FACTOR 2
6: #define MAX_BONES 251
7: #define FLAT_SHADED
8: uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
9: uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
10: uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
11: uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
12: uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
13: uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
14: attribute vec3 position;
15: attribute vec3 normal;
16: attribute vec2 uv;
17: #ifdef USE_COLOR
18:     attribute vec3 color;
19: #endif
20: #ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS
21:     attribute vec3 morphTarget0;
22:     attribute vec3 morphTarget1;
23:     attribute vec3 morphTarget2;
24:     attribute vec3 morphTarget3;
25:     #ifdef USE_MORPHNORMALS
26:         attribute vec3 morphNormal0;
27:         attribute vec3 morphNormal1;
28:         attribute vec3 morphNormal2;
29:         attribute vec3 morphNormal3;
30:     #else
31:         attribute vec3 morphTarget4;
32:         attribute vec3 morphTarget5;
33:         attribute vec3 morphTarget6;
34:         attribute vec3 morphTarge[…]  three.min.js:716:348
THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment WARNING: 0:1: extension 'GL_ARB_gpu_shader5' is not supported
 1: #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
2: precision highp float;
3: precision highp int;
4: #define SHADER_NAME MeshPhongMaterial
5: #define GAMMA_FACTOR 2
6: #define FLAT_SHADED
7: uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
8: uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
9: #define TONE_MAPPING
10: #define saturate(a) clamp( a, 0.0, 1.0 )
11: uniform float toneMappingExposure;
12: uniform float toneMappingWhitePoint;
13: vec3 LinearToneMapping( vec3 color ) {
14:   return toneMappingExposure * color;
15: }
16: vec3 ReinhardToneMapping( vec3 color ) {
17:   color *= toneMappingExposure;
18:   return saturate( color / ( vec3( 1.0 ) + color ) );
19: }
20: #define Uncharted2Helper( x ) max( ( ( x * ( 0.15 * x + 0.10 * 0.50 ) + 0.20 * 0.02 ) / ( x * ( 0.15 * x + 0.50 ) + 0.20 * 0.30 ) ) - 0.02 / 0.30, vec3( 0.0 ) )
21: vec3 Uncharted2ToneMapping( vec3 color ) {
22:   color *= toneMappingExposure;
23:   return saturate( Uncharted2Helper( color ) / Uncharted2Helper( vec3( toneMappingWhitePoint ) ) );
24: }
25: ve[…]  three.min.js:716:348
THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() vertex WARNING: 0:1: extension 'GL_ARB_gpu_shader5' is not supported
 1: precision highp float;
2: precision highp int;
3: #define SHADER_NAME LineBasicMaterial
4: #define VERTEX_TEXTURES
5: #define GAMMA_FACTOR 2
6: #define MAX_BONES 251
7: uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
8: uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
9: uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
10: uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
11: uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
12: uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
13: attribute vec3 position;
14: attribute vec3 normal;
15: attribute vec2 uv;
16: #ifdef USE_COLOR
17:     attribute vec3 color;
18: #endif
19: #ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS
20:     attribute vec3 morphTarget0;
21:     attribute vec3 morphTarget1;
22:     attribute vec3 morphTarget2;
23:     attribute vec3 morphTarget3;
24:     #ifdef USE_MORPHNORMALS
25:         attribute vec3 morphNormal0;
26:         attribute vec3 morphNormal1;
27:         attribute vec3 morphNormal2;
28:         attribute vec3 morphNormal3;
29:     #else
30:         attribute vec3 morphTarget4;
31:         attribute vec3 morphTarget5;
32:         attribute vec3 morphTarget6;
33:         attribute vec3 morphTarget7;
34:     #endif
35: #endif
36: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
37:     attribute vec4 skinIndex;
38:     attribute vec4 skinWeight;
39: #endif
40: 
41: #define PI 3.14159
42: #define PI2 6.28318
43: #define RECIPROCAL_PI 0.31830988618
44: #define RECIPROCAL_PI2 0.15915494
45: #define LOG2 1.442695
46: #define EPSILON 1e-6
47: #define saturate(a) clamp( a, 0.0, 1.0 )
48: #define whiteCompliment(a) ( 1.0 - saturate( a ) )
49: float pow2( const in float x ) { return x*x; }
50: float pow3( const in float x ) { return x*x*x; }
51: float pow4( const in float x ) { float x2 = x*x; return x2*x2; }
52: float average( const in vec3 color ) { return dot( color, vec3( 0.3333 ) ); }
53: struct IncidentLight {
54:     vec3 color;
55:     vec3 direction;
56:     bool visible;
57: };
58: struct ReflectedLight {
59:     vec3 directDiffuse;
60:     vec3 directSpecular;
61:     vec3 indirectDiffuse;
62:     vec3 indirectSpecular;
63: };
64: struct GeometricContext {
65:     vec3 position;
66:     vec3 normal;
67:     vec3 viewDir;
68: };
69: vec3 transformDirection( in vec3 dir, in mat4 matrix ) {
70:     return normalize( ( matrix * vec4( dir, 0.0 ) ).xyz );
71: }
72: vec3 inverseTransformDirection( in vec3 dir, in mat4 matrix ) {
73:     return normalize( ( vec4( dir, 0.0 ) * matrix ).xyz );
74: }
75: vec3 projectOnPlane(in vec3 point, in vec3 pointOnPlane, in vec3 planeNormal ) {
76:     float distance = dot( planeNormal, point - pointOnPlane );
77:     return - distance * planeNormal + point;
78: }
79: float sideOfPlane( in vec3 point, in vec3 pointOnPlane, in vec3 planeNormal ) {
80:     return sign( dot( point - pointOnPlane, planeNormal ) );
81: }
82: vec3 linePlaneIntersect( in vec3 pointOnLine, in vec3 lineDirection, in vec3 pointOnPlane, in vec3 planeNormal ) {
83:     return lineDirection * ( dot( planeNormal, pointOnPlane - pointOnLine ) / dot( planeNormal, lineDirection ) ) + pointOnLine;
84: }
85: 
86: #if defined( USE_MAP ) || defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) || defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) || defined( USE_SPECULARMAP ) || defined( USE_ALPHAMAP ) || defined( USE_EMISSIVEMAP ) || defined( USE_ROUGHNESSMAP ) || defined( USE_METALNESSMAP )
87:     varying vec2 vUv;
88:     uniform vec4 offsetRepeat;
89: #endif
90: 
91: #if defined( USE_LIGHTMAP ) || defined( USE_AOMAP )
92:     attribute vec2 uv2;
93:     varying vec2 vUv2;
94: #endif
95: #if defined( USE_ENVMAP ) && ! defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) && ! defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) && ! defined( PHONG ) && ! defined( STANDARD )
96:     varying vec3 vReflect;
97:     uniform float refractionRatio;
98: #endif
99: 
100: #ifdef USE_COLOR
101:    varying vec3 vColor;
102: #endif
103: #ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS
104:    #ifndef USE_MORPHNORMALS
105:    uniform float morphTargetInfluences[ 8 ];
106:    #else
107:    uniform float morphTargetInfluences[ 4 ];
108:    #endif
109: #endif
110: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
111:    uniform mat4 bindMatrix;
112:    uniform mat4 bindMatrixInverse;
113:    #ifdef BONE_TEXTURE
114:        uniform sampler2D boneTexture;
115:        uniform int boneTextureWidth;
116:        uniform int boneTextureHeight;
117:        mat4 getBoneMatrix( const in float i ) {
118:            float j = i * 4.0;
119:            float x = mod( j, float( boneTextureWidth ) );
120:            float y = floor( j / float( boneTextureWidth ) );
121:            float dx = 1.0 / float( boneTextureWidth );
122:            float dy = 1.0 / float( boneTextureHeight );
123:            y = dy * ( y + 0.5 );
124:            vec4 v1 = texture2D( boneTexture, vec2( dx * ( x + 0.5 ), y ) );
125:            vec4 v2 = texture2D( boneTexture, vec2( dx * ( x + 1.5 ), y ) );
126:            vec4 v3 = texture2D( boneTexture, vec2( dx * ( x + 2.5 ), y ) );
127:            vec4 v4 = texture2D( boneTexture, vec2( dx * ( x + 3.5 ), y ) );
128:            mat4 bone = mat4( v1, v2, v3, v4 );
129:            return bone;
130:        }
131:    #else
132:        uniform mat4 boneGlobalMatrices[ MAX_BONES ];
133:        mat4 getBoneMatrix( const in float i ) {
134:            mat4 bone = boneGlobalMatrices[ int(i) ];
135:            return bone;
136:        }
137:    #endif
138: #endif
139: 
140: #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF
141:    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
142:        varying float vFragDepth;
143:    #endif
144:    uniform float logDepthBufFC;
145: #endif
146: void main() {
147:    #if defined( USE_MAP ) || defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) || defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) || defined( USE_SPECULARMAP ) || defined( USE_ALPHAMAP ) || defined( USE_EMISSIVEMAP ) || defined( USE_ROUGHNESSMAP ) || defined( USE_METALNESSMAP )
148:    vUv = uv * offsetRepeat.zw + offsetRepeat.xy;
149: #endif
150:    #if defined( USE_LIGHTMAP ) || defined( USE_AOMAP )
151:    vUv2 = uv2;
152: #endif
153:    #ifdef USE_COLOR
154:    vColor.xyz = color.xyz;
155: #endif
156:    #ifdef USE_SKINNING
157:    mat4 boneMatX = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.x );
158:    mat4 boneMatY = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.y );
159:    mat4 boneMatZ = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.z );
160:    mat4 boneMatW = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.w );
161: #endif
162:    #ifdef USE_ENVMAP
163:    
164: vec3 objectNormal = vec3( normal );
165: 
166:    #ifdef USE_MORPHNORMALS
167:    objectNormal += ( morphNormal0 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ];
168:    objectNormal += ( morphNormal1 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 1 ];
169:    objectNormal += ( morphNormal2 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 2 ];
170:    objectNormal += ( morphNormal3 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 3 ];
171: #endif
172: 
173:    #ifdef USE_SKINNING
174:    mat4 skinMatrix = mat4( 0.0 );
175:    skinMatrix += skinWeight.x * boneMatX;
176:    skinMatrix += skinWeight.y * boneMatY;
177:    skinMatrix += skinWeight.z * boneMatZ;
178:    skinMatrix += skinWeight.w * boneMatW;
179:    skinMatrix  = bindMatrixInverse * skinMatrix * bindMatrix;
180:    objectNormal = vec4( skinMatrix * vec4( objectNormal, 0.0 ) ).xyz;
181: #endif
182: 
183:    #ifdef FLIP_SIDED
184:    objectNormal = -objectNormal;
185: #endif
186: vec3 transformedNormal = normalMatrix * objectNormal;
187: 
188:    #endif
189:    
190: vec3 transformed = vec3( position );
191: 
192:    #ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS
193:    transformed += ( morphTarget0 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ];
194:    transformed += ( morphTarget1 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 1 ];
195:    transformed += ( morphTarget2 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 2 ];
196:    transformed += ( morphTarget3 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 3 ];
197:    #ifndef USE_MORPHNORMALS
198:    transformed += ( morphTarget4 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 4 ];
199:    transformed += ( morphTarget5 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 5 ];
200:    transformed += ( morphTarget6 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 6 ];
201:    transformed += ( morphTarget7 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 7 ];
202:    #endif
203: #endif
204: 
205:    #ifdef USE_SKINNING
206:    vec4 skinVertex = bindMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );
207:    vec4 skinned = vec4( 0.0 );
208:    skinned += boneMatX * skinVertex * skinWeight.x;
209:    skinned += boneMatY * skinVertex * skinWeight.y;
210:    skinned += boneMatZ * skinVertex * skinWeight.z;
211:    skinned += boneMatW * skinVertex * skinWeight.w;
212:    skinned  = bindMatrixInverse * skinned;
213: #endif
214: 
215:    #ifdef USE_SKINNING
216:    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * skinned;
217: #else
218:    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );
219: #endif
220: gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
221: 
222:    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF
223:    gl_Position.z = log2(max( EPSILON, gl_Position.w + 1.0 )) * logDepthBufFC;
224:    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
225:        vFragDepth = 1.0 + gl_Position.w;
226:    #else
227:        gl_Position.z = (gl_Position.z - 1.0) * gl_Position.w;
228:    #endif
229: #endif
230: 
231:    #if defined( USE_ENVMAP ) || defined( PHONG ) || defined( STANDARD ) || defined( LAMBERT ) || defined ( USE_SHADOWMAP )
232:    #ifdef USE_SKINNING
233:        vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * skinned;
234:    #else
235:        vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );
236:    #endif
237: #endif
238: 
239:    #if defined( USE_ENVMAP ) && ! defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) && ! defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) && ! defined( PHONG ) && ! defined( STANDARD )
240:    vec3 cameraToVertex = normalize( worldPosition.xyz - cameraPosition );
241:    vec3 worldNormal = inverseTransformDirection( transformedNormal, viewMatrix );
242:    #ifdef ENVMAP_MODE_REFLECTION
243:        vReflect = reflect( cameraToVertex, worldNormal );
244:    #else
245:        vReflect = refract( cameraToVertex, worldNormal, refractionRatio );
246:    #endif
247: #endif
248: 
249: }
250:   three.min.js:716:348
```

Why do I get these weird warnings? Where could they come from?

On Chrome, I don't get these warnings.